# Fastest way to compute HCF of 2 numbers

Tags: algorithms

I want a very quick `non recursive method` for finding the HCF (Highest Common Factor) of 2 `very large numbers`

Comment: How large are your very large numbers?

Comment: Consider the both the numbers to be a 100 digits in length each (both are integers ofcourse)

Answer (score 2):

For example, http://www.lysator.liu.se/~nisse/archive/sgcd.pdf gives a discussion of sub-quadratic methods for finding the GCD (in particular Schoenhage's algorithm.)